# Flutter webview navigationDelegate called twice

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to download files which contains a certain url pattern with Flutter web view. This works but in this case the browser is opened twice, as the navigationDelegate is called twice. NavigationRequest Object is same except `isForMainFrame` property. It is false for first time, and true for second time.

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(middle: Text(_appTitle)),
  child: Container(
    child: SafeArea(
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: _stackToView,
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            key: _key,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            initialUrl: this._connectionString,
            onPageStarted: (value) => setState(() {
              if (shouldChangeStack) {
                _stackToView = 1;
              } else {
                _stackToView = 0;
              }

            }),
            onPageFinished: (value) => setState(() {
              _stackToView = 0;
            }),
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) async {
              print(request.url);
              if (request.url.contains("download")) {
                setState(() {
                  shouldChangeStack = false;
                });
                if (await canLaunch(request.url)) {
                  await launch(request.url);
                }
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  shouldChangeStack = true;
                });
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              }
            },
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      top: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I don't get what is the question, is it how to not call the delegate twice?

Comment: @LoVe Basically I want to download the file with built in safari, however when I intercept the url with NavigationDelegate, it opens safari twice. While I want it to be opened once only.

Comment: you can track if the page was opened with a boolean, set it to true after opening the page and wrap you delegate method with an if statement to check if page was launched before, tell me if this suits you

Comment: Yeah I tried that, that seems a workaround, wanted to understand why it calls the Delegate method twice. If there is any cleaner approach

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the delegate method is called twice was because `setState()` is called. This causes the entire `Widget build()` to be rebuilt. As previously mentioned in the comments, a workaround for this issue is to set a checker before launching the page and define if the page needs to be opened.